# Windows Mobile - Disable USB (Compact Framework - C#)

Tags: c#, security, windows-mobile, opennetcf, compact-framework2.0

I need to disable USB on Windows Mobile. How to disable USB on Windows Mobile using Compact Framework 2.0 (C#)? I am using OpenNETCF too. If it has some class to disable USB, I can use it too.

Comment: I don't expect that there is an API to do this.

Comment: Why is your code so special that it ought to be allowed to do this?

Comment: It is the security enforced by enterprise to thier employee.

Comment: If it's windows mobile 6.1 or later, I wouldn't try and do this myself - there's a pack for System Center (Mobile Device Management) that lets you have granular control over such features using group policy.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of advice, you have to implement both operations to lock / unlock the usb device. Because if you can't unlock it you must perform a clean boot.

You should provision the device with this specific policies

```
<!-- DenyRAPI.xml !-->
<wap-provisioningdoc>
    <characteristic type="SecurityPolicy">
        <parm name="4097" value="0"/>
    </characteristic>
</wap-provisioningdoc>

<!-- AllowRAPI.xml !-->
<wap-provisioningdoc>
    <characteristic type="SecurityPolicy">
        <parm name="4097" value="2"/>
    </characteristic>
</wap-provisioningdoc>
```

I provide a link to the original post in which is suggested that you create the cabs.
[Original Post](http://bansky.net/blog/2007/07/prevent-device-connection-to-the-desktop-pc/)

I have used another approach to read the XML configuration and then using the following method I execute the provisioning

```
Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ProcessConfiguration(XmlDocument,boolean);
```

Another option is to use builds the cabs and install them by using wceload.exe

Comment: I will try and let you know about results.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is code-signed and running in full trust, then you have access to protected registry keys. You could then try to edit or remove the various USB device driver configuration registry values. Then you **might** have disabled USB.

**Edit:** Possibly involved registry keys:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Drivers\USB\FunctionDrivers

Comment: I will try and let you know. Can you give me example of "protected registry keys"?